# SQL agent job for data archiving

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent-job, archiving

I need to use the SQL agent job to do a Data Archiving for a database. I have to query the job to run the Archiving. I directly put the query in the command window for the first step in the agent job.

When I click the parse button the following error message comes out:

```
now is not a recognized built-in function name
```

The query that I used to archive the data is like

```
    DELETE [] FROM []
    JOIN [] ON [] = []
    WHERE BusinessDayDate < now() - 395
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `getdate()` instead of `now()`?  `now()` is not a SQL Server built-in function.  It's a MySQL built-in function.

Comment: Yes, and thanks for your help! But when I am running this agent job, it gave me the error: DELETE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1934). The step failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GETDATE()`- [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is the SQL Server equivalent of `Now()`.

Try replacing the same in your code -

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
DELETE [] FROM []
    JOIN [] ON [] = []
    WHERE BusinessDayDate < GETDATE() - 395
```

Edit: Added `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`.

Reason: The `DELETE` failed as there might be -
a primary xml index on the table and/or
filtered indexes, indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns on the table.

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER must be ON when you are creating or changing indexes on computed columns or indexed views. If SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, CREATE, UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements on tables with indexes on computed columns or indexed views will fail.A good read - [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190356.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But when I am running this agent job, it gave me the error: DELETE failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 1934).  The step failed.

Comment: @YaqunPeng Add the query `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` to the SQL Agent to run right before the DELETE statement.  It should be in the same command window.  SQL Server Management Studio turns it on by default, but SQL Agent doesn't.

Comment: @YaqunPeng - glad to help, please accept the answer. This would help the community when anyone searches for a similar kind of problem in future.